# Need help with my topology when sculpting and using boolean mod

Tags: mesh, modifiers, sculpting

I used a mesh to cut out a part of my sculpture, but the wound left behind on the topology is ridiculous, I cant use any tools on the wound, or it gets a super rough crazy triangle texture :s

Wound shown
[image: Wound on topology shown]
Topological mess after inflation
[image: Topological mess after inflation]
Close up of topological disaster
[image]

Comment: Try to ease this out with the Smooth brush afterwards...